# Prediction values change every time tensorflow js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Prediction of a binary outputs changes every time I train model. I want it to be same all the time I train the neural network. How can I achieve that.

```
function createModel() {

  // Add a single input layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [25], units: neurons, useBias: true,activation:H_activation}));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: neurons, useBias: true,activation:H_activation}));
 
  //model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 30, useBias: true,activation:'relu'}));
  // Add an output layer
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 5, activation:'sigmoid'}));

  return model;
}
```

Comment: This is contradictory. Training a neural network changes the weights of the network. You cannot want the output of the network to be the same, and want to train it, at the same time.

Comment: every time with same dataset model gives different output. so I want it to be same